# Bad if I use adapter of higher Ampere?

Tags: adapter

I'm looking for an adapter for my Keyboard piano. I am not sure about the specifications of the original adapter, but I've looked up some online and I've found two adapters that supposedly should fit my keyboard. The problem is that one of them says for the output: 12V 1A while the other is 12V 600mA.

My broken adapter is not original but it says Output: 12V 600mA on it.

Is it very bad if I would use the 1 Ampere adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not wrong to use the 1A adaptor.

The current rating of the adaptor is the maximum current that can be drawn from it and not the current the equipment will draw.

It is good if the current rating of the adaptor is higher than the current rating of the equipment.

Regards,

Nandu.